# What causes Newtonsoft JSON to serialize $type and $value?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a subset of request headers in an `HttpContext` with Newtonsoft JSON.  If I just throw `HttpContext.Request.Headers` at it, I get key-value pairs of the header and its values as an array:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    ctx.Request.Headers
);
```

... gives:

```
{
  "Accept": [
        "text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,application\/xml;q=0.9,image\/avif,image\/webp,image\/apng,*\/*;q=0.8"
  ],
  "Host": [
        "localhost:44383"
  ],
  ...
```

But if I try to remove some with LINQ I start getting `$type` and `$value` serialized for each entry:

```
IDictionary<string, object?> headers = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var header in ctx.Request.Headers.Where(x => x.Key != "Cookie")) {
    headers[header.Key] = header.Value.AsEnumerable();
}
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    headers
);
```

... gives:

```
{
  "Accept": {
    "$type": "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives",
    "$values": [
            "text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,application\/xml;q=0.9,image\/avif,image\/webp,image\/apng,*\/*;q=0.8"
    ]
  },
  "Host": {
    "$type": "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives",
    "$values": [
            "localhost:44383"
    ]
  },
  ...
```

What's causing this different serialization, and how can I get it to serialize my modified dictionary the same way it does when I just pass it `ctx.Request.Headers`?

Comment: `$type` and `$value` are present when you serialized your JSON with [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) equal to `TypeNameHandling.Arrays`, `All` or maybe `Auto`.   This is **not** the default value, so you must have set this setting somewhere, possibly even through [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm).  You need to search your source code to see where `TypeNameHandling` is enabled.  Please [edit] your question to update with a [mcve] showing how this setting is enabled.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Please provide a [mre] and specify .NET and Json.NET versions used.

Comment: Also why not just `IDictionary<string, StringValues?> headers = new Dictionary<string, StringValues?>();` and `headers[header.Key] = header.Value;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd set `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` elsewhere, and needed to set it to `TypeNameHandling.None` for this call to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, which fixed the problem.

The `$type` and `$value` were getting serialized for the `ExpandoObject` because the `Auto` setting "includes the .NET type name when the type of the object being serialized is not the same as its declared type."

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft.Json doesn't like dynamics. I think it makes some sense to use naitive Newtonsoft objects

```
        JObject headers = new();
        foreach (var header in response.Headers.Where(x => x.Key != "Cookie"))
            headers[header.Key] = new JArray(header.Value.AsEnumerable());

        string serialized = headers.ToString();
```

or if for some reason you need a dictionary, create an instance of a dictionary explicitly

```
Dictionary<string,object?> headers = new();
```